# What pattern to use to generate UUID when storing a model in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel-9

I want to use a UUID as a part of a URL:

```
https://example.com/books/fiction/don-quixote-37d8d0a6-692a-11ed-9022-0242ac120002
```

Where in my controller should I generate this UUD?

```
class BookController extends Controller
    {
    public function store(BookStoreRequest $request)
        {
        $this->authorize('create', Book::class);
        
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $validated['identifier'] = (string) Str::uuid();
        
        $book = Book::create($validated);    
        }
     }
```

Above results in the error:

```
SQLSTATE Field 'identifier' doesn't have a default value
```

This assume that the value for `identifier` wasn't passed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add a boot function to the model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->identifier = Str::uuid();
    });
}
```